# How can I ask for more quota and how much does the request to the Google Maps Geolocation API cost?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-mobile

I developed a mobile app based on the Google Gears API

URL from the API: https://developers.google.com/gears/

But the API is not supported anymore.

I want to migrate my app to the Google Maps Geolocation API.

URL from the API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation

I check the features of the Geolocation API and it seems it is the best solution to migrate my app maintaining the functionalities I had using the Gears API.

I was developing the migration but I finished my daily quota.

When I ask for more quota on the Google API console, I am redirected a form to contact a Google sales executive.

On the other hand, I enabled the billing and I have a credit of 15$ but even though I can not change my daily quota.

How can I ask for more daily request quota and how much money does it cost?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to contact to Google Sales for using Google Maps Geolocation API, because Google doesn't provide for free quota except for testing quota (100 times/day).
And you might also need to buy Google Maps API for business license, the geolocation API might require the business license.
So asking to Google Sales is only available option.

Comment: I have already contact sales if I can use only the Geolocation API because it is my only need. Let's see what happen. Thanks for your answer.